# Get key/value pairs as arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, split, slice

I've been struggling with this: Complete the keysAndValues function so that it takes in an object and returns the keys and values as separate arrays.

I've added several versions so you can see how i'm thinking through the problem.

```
def keysAndValues(data)
      data.each do |data|
        data.split(key.to_a, value.to_a)
      end
      data
    end


keysAndValues ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})


def keysAndValues(data)
  data.each do |data|
    data.split([key], [value])
  end
  data
end

keysAndValues ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})


def keysAndValues(data)
  data.each do |data|
    data.slice([key], [value])
  end
  data
end

keysAndValues ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})



def keysAndValues(data)
  data.each do |data|
    data.slice_to.a(2)([ :a ], [ ' ' ])
  end
  data
end

keysAndValues ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})



def keysAndValues(data)
  data.each.slice_to.a(2) { |x, y| [x], [y] }
  end
  data
end

keysAndValues ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def keysAndValues(data)
  [data.keys, data.values]
end

keys, values = keysAndValues({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})

keys
# => [:a, :b, :c] 
values
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Please note that `keysAndValues` is not following the Ruby naming convention. The correct name should be `keys_and_values`.

Comment: Can't believe i missed the Ruby convention! A sign i've spent far too long trying to solve it! I see why i kept getting an undefined method error - i didn't define keys or value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are built-in methods for that:

```
irb(main):001:0> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.keys
=> [:a, :b, :c]
irb(main):002:0> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.values
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Or, maybe you want this? (Sorry, your question is not clear to me)

```
irb(main):003:0> Array({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def keys_and_values(data)
  return data.keys, data.values
end
```

thus:

data_hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}

keys_and_values(data_hash)

returns:

```
[[a:, b:, c:, d:], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```